# Android TalkBack in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, talkback

when talkback enabled, if page has more content than the screen size, swiping right after the last element in the screen view not scrolling to the next element of RecyclerView.

**XML Code:**

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/included_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/header_layout" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:fontFamily="@font/msr_700"
        android:text="@string/lbl_intro_user_guide"
        android:textColor="@color/gunmetal"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/guide_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?  I am seeing a similar issue.

Comment: No. Still facing this issue on some devices

Answer (score 2):

The following line stops the autoscrolling, removing it will fix the behaviour:

```
   android:importantForAccessibility="no"
```

Do not set `importantForAccessibility` as `no` for RecyclerView, it breaks functionality such as auto scrolling.

Comment: that's completely true, you shouldn't set importance to "NO" for recyclerViews.